# How to deserialize JSON to sObject?

Tags: apex, json, sobject, deserialize

I have following code and I'm trying to deserialize json array to list of sObjects, but I'm getting following exception without any message:

> System.JSONException:

```
String dzejson = '[{"attributes":{"name":"Test"}}]';

List<sObject> objs = (List<sObject>)JSON.deserialize(dzejson, List<sObject>.class);

System.Debug(objs);
```

Comment: add the exception message

Comment: @blackPerlSAF there is no exception printed out saddly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON should have following format:

```
String dzejson = '[{"attributes":{"type":"Contact"}, "lastName":"Test"}]';
```