# Can I mock out lookup relationship using FFLIB ApexMocks

Tags: unit-test, fflib, apexmock

I'm trying to mock out something similar to the following structure:

- Task.LastModifiedBy.Username;
- Task.LookupRelationshipToUser__r.Username;

Using the makeRelationships method for this doesn't make sense to me so far. I've used the makeRelationships method to mock out parent to child relationships successfully for mocking out queries but I'm at a loss with on how to proceed with this method.

Using the setReadonlyFields allows me to set Task.LastModifiedById to a mocked Users Id, but then when my code attempts to reference Task.LastModifiedBy.UserName I get null pointer errors while running test. I've tried using this method to set Task.LastModifiedBy.Username but I get error saying it doesn't recognize LastModifiedBy while deploying.

Maybe my terminology is off so searching around and looking at the FFLIB/Apexmocks resources hasn't been helpful so far. If anyone has any advice or can point me in the direction of some examples or documentation I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried deserializing a string into the object with the lookups set? Better yet there's this library that lets you do this https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator

Comment: I've tried to convince people to add SObjectFabricator to our codebase but it falls on deaf ears. I'm going to start searching around and testing out the deserializing methods and see what I come up with. I was stuck on the idea that there was a method in Apexmocks that would do this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Let me write up an example on how to do it.

Comment: SObjectFabricator is great stuff -- I've used it for years without issue and is essential for easy-to-read mocks of hierarchies including autonumber, formula, and system audit-type fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment about not being able to use SObjectFabricator, you can deserialize a string into an object with these fields/relationships set.

This is pretty crude, but it works. Use it as a starting point.

```
Group_Member__c groupMember = new Group_Member__c(
    Id = TestUtils.generateId(Group_Member__c.SObjectType),
    Group__c = TestUtils.generateId(Group__c.SObjectType)
);
String groupJSON =
    '{"attributes": {"type": "Group__c"}, "Id": "' +
    groupMember.Group__c +
    '", "Name": "Test Group", "Group_Members__r": {"done": true, "totalSize": 1, "records":' +
    JSON.serialize(new List<Group_Member__c>{ groupMember }) +
    '}}';
Group__c mockGroup = (Group__c) JSON.deserialize(groupJSON, SObject.class);
```

This will serialize into a custom `Group__c` object with its child relationship `Group_Members__r` populated with the `Group_Member__c` records.

There are some other posts around this site that explain the format:

[How to deserialize JSON to sObject?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171926/how-to-deserialize-json-to-sobject)

[Deserialize JSON to SObject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106309/deserialize-json-to-sobject)

Comment: You've given me a lot to work with, thank you!